# Linear Complexity of Product of Two LFSRs

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, cryptography, coding-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of theorem 3.5 on page 67/68 in Andreas Klein's [book on stream ciphers](https://books.google.ch/books?id=GYpEAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=a%20klein%20stream%20ciphers%20product%20of%20two%20lfsr&source=bl&ots=ULM2aG2okt&sig=NELIm82qWeD6l2RPoJnB8i80T6g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihi_uB9MjPAhUFWhoKHYuPC-0Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=a%20klein%20stream%20ciphers%20product%20of%20two%20lfsr&f=false). It states that $\zeta_j^{(l)}$ are the roots of the polynomial $f^{(l)*}$, i.e. $f^{(l)}(z)= \prod_{k'=1}^{k_l}\prod_{j=1}^{n_{k'}}(1-z \zeta_j^{(l)})=\prod_{j=1}^{n_1^{(l)}}(1-z \zeta_j^{(l)})^{e_j^{(l)}}$

My first question is: Why are the $\zeta_j^{(l)}$ roots of both $f_l$ and $f_l^*$? Does one know that they are roots of unity?

My second question is: How can I deduce the feedback polynomial of the product stream from the closed form? And why is it the feedback polynomial of the minimal LFSR if all $\zeta_j^{(1)}\zeta_k^{(2)}$ are different?

My confusion stems from the fact that the notation for $f$ and $f^*$ seems to be slightly interchangeable throughout the book.